# Cypher - create relationship using value of calculation

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm working on Neo4j and manipulate data using their REST API and Cypher.
I have the following code:

```
MATCH (u:USER) WHERE id(u) = 10192
MATCH (uc:USERS_CLUSTER) WHERE id(uc) = 19618
MATCH (u)-[r1:HAVE]->(i:ITEM)<-[r2:HAVE]-(u2:USER)-[ic:IN_CLUSTER]->(uc)
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[oldic:IN_CLUSTER]->(uc)
WHERE (u) <> (u2)
DELETE oldic
// --> PROBLEM --> CREAT (u)-[:IN_CLUSTER {score: XXXXXXXXX}]->(uc)
RETURN id(u),u,id(uc),uc,
// --> VALUE --> 
((avg(abs(2-abs(r1.rank-r2.rank))*(2-abs(r1.rank-r2.rank)))+4)/8)*100 as calcedMatch
ORDER BY calcedMatch DESC
```

There is a value `calcedMatch` I'm calculating, and I'm able to return it without any problem. But what I would like to do is create a new IN_CLUSTER relation and having a property `score` with value of the calcedMatch (Where I put the XXXXXXXX). Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is advisable to not use the id of a node as a reference; it is not immutable in the context of the assigned node or relationship (i.e. they can be reused when objects are destroyed).

I updated your query a little. You do not need to delete the relationship and then recreate it.  You can simply use `MERGE` and it will create it if it is not present.  Then you can set the new score on it afterwards.

```
MATCH (u:USER) WHERE id(u) = 10192
WITH u
MATCH (uc:USERS_CLUSTER) WHERE id(uc) = 19618
WITH uc
MATCH (u)-[r1:HAVE]->(i:ITEM)<-[r2:HAVE]-(u2:USER)-[ic:IN_CLUSTER]->(uc)
WHERE (u) <> (u2)
WITH u, uc, ((avg(abs(2-abs(r1.rank-r2.rank))*(2-abs(r1.rank-r2.rank)))+4)/8)*100 as calcedMatch
MERGE (u)-[ic:IN_CLUSTER]->(uc)
set ic.score = calcedMatch
RETURN id(u),u,id(uc),uc, ic.score
ORDER BY ic.score DESC
```

Comment: the id is immutable it is just reused after deletions :)